# 401 Error When Uploading File to SharePoint Online with SaveBinaryDirect (C#)

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-online

I am developing a tool that is supposed to upload files from a local drive to SharePoint online.

When I try to upload the file via SharePoint.Client.File.SaveBinaryDirect() I get a 401: Not authorized error

Here is my code:

```
var uploadFilePath = @"C:\TestFiles\testFile.pdf";
var uploadFileRelativePath = "/sites/my-site/MyLibrary/testFile.pdf";

using (var ctx = new AuthenticationManager().GetAppOnlyAuthenticatedContext(site,
                    ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ClientId"], ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ClientSecret"]))
{
    using (var fileStream = new FileStream(uploadFilePath, FileMode.Open))
    {
        File.SaveBinaryDirect(ctx, uploadFileRelativePath, fileStream, true);
    }
}
```

The thing is, it works fine if I exchange the SaveBinaryDirect with the following code:

```
FileCreationInformation newFile = new FileCreationInformation();
newFile.Content = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(uploadFilePath);
newFile.Url = "testFile.pdf";
List docs = ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("MyLibrary");
docs.RootFolder.Files.Add(newFile);
ctx.ExecuteQuery();
```

So my tool is clearly authorized to upload files. It just doesn't work with SaveBinaryDirect.

I would still like to upload the file with SharePoint.Client.File.SaveBinaryDirect. It's way less code and I don't have to manually get the list and folders.

Do you have any idea why I might get that 401 error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use app only token with SaveBinaryDirect method: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/upload-large-files-sample-app-for-sharepoint
:

> Only use this method if you're using a user-only authentication policy. A user-only authentication policy isn't available in a SharePoint Add-in, but can be used in native device add-ins, Windows PowerShell, and Windows console applications.

Comment: That explains the error, thank you. 
Do you know whether it’s possible to use the authentication of the user who is running the tool? I know it was possible with SharePoint 2019. I’m unsure about Online though.

Comment: Sorry, I do not know ;)

Comment: I just hit this - strangely our code had long been using SaveBinaryDirect with app-only tokens, but it appears it was only working because the site we'd been using it on was configured with particularly open permissions.  On a more typical site it definitely doesn't work, wasted hours trying to figure out why this was happening (and had googled but couldn't find the above article initially)